# Garnish event when changing category group

Tags: categories, javascript, garnish

When I am on the categories index (admin/categories), is there a Garnish event that fires when you select a different category group in the sidebar? I want to add some custom JS after the AJAX request completes and the elements have been added to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Craft.elementIndex.on('selectSource', function(){
     alert('changed the source');
});
```

`Craft.elementIndex` contains the plugin for all index pages, that means all entries as well as users and categories. There is an `updateElements` event as well..

Here is a full list

> afterInit
>
> selectSource
>
> selectSite
>
> updateElements
>
> selectionChange
>
> enableElements
>
> disableElements
>
> afterAction